# How can I create a seamless backdrop with python in Blender?

Tags: python, scripting, blender

I want to create a seamless backdrop for my blender project. It's done in a script and I want to add the backdrop to that script.

The problem is that I don't figure how to extrude a plane only in an edge so I can later bevel it and make it seamless. It's really easy to do with the GUI but I don't know how to do it in scripting.

I'm trying a few things, but for now I only have this code (which is obviously unfinished and not very well done):

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(radius=1, view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 0), layers=(True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False))
plane2 = bpy.data.objects['Plane']

dims = plane2.dimensions
plane2.dimensions = 100, 70, 35

bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()

bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(use_extend=False, use_expand=False, type='EDGE')

bpy.context.scene.objects[0].data.edges[0]

me = bpy.context.object.data
"""
# Get a BMesh representation
bm = bmesh.new()   # create an empty BMesh
bm.from_mesh(me)   # fill it in from a Mesh


# Modify the BMesh, can do anything here...
for e in bm.edges:
    e.co.x += 1.0
"""
bpy.context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode = (False, True, False)

bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move(MESH_OT_extrude_region={"mirror":False}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0, 0, 88.1553), "constraint_axis":(False, False, True), "constraint_orientation":'GLOBAL', "mirror":False, "proportional":'DISABLED', "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False})

bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
```

I want the backdrop to look like this, in case it helps to understand better the goal:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ycz1wQY_7KI

Answer (score 1):

As you only need two faces for the backdrop, I would make the mesh from a python list. Then add a bevel modifier to round out the back corner.

```
import bpy
from bpy_extras.object_utils import object_data_add
from mathutils import Vector

verts = [
    Vector(( 50,-35,  0)),
    Vector(( 50, 35,  0)),
    Vector((-50, 35,  0)),
    Vector((-50,-35,  0)),
    Vector((-50, 35, 35)),
    Vector(( 50, 35, 35)),
]
faces = [[2,3,0,1], [5,4,2,1]]

mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name="Backdrop")
mesh.from_pydata(verts, [], faces)
object_data_add(bpy.context, mesh)
backdrop = bpy.context.object
bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()

bev_mod = backdrop.modifiers.new('bevel', 'BEVEL')
bev_mod.width = 12
bev_mod.segments = 5

mat = bpy.data.materials.new('back_mat')
if bpy.app.version[1] < 80:
    mat.diffuse_color = [1,1,1] # white
else:
    # 2.80 needs alpha value in colour
    mat.diffuse_color = [1,1,1,1]
backdrop.active_material = mat
```

Comment: Ok I will try later and I'll tell you, sorry for the late reply and thanks man!